# Argsort doesn't work in combination with numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba, np.argsort

I have some problems with the application of np.argsort in combination with numba.
The input coord is a two-dimensional array consisting of coordinate which need to be sorted in counter-clockwise manner. All the variables are float64 and numy array's.

```
@jit
def sortVertices(coord):
    yr = coord[:, 1]
    xc = coord[:, 0]
    xl = np.array([xc.size])
    yl = np.array([yr.size])
    center_xc = np.sum(xc)/xl
    center_yr = np.sum(yr)/yl
    theta = np.arctan2(yr-center_yr, xc-center_xc) * 180.0 / np.pi
    indices = np.argsort(theta)
    x = xc[indices]
    y = yr[indices]
    coord_new = np.vstack((x, y)).T
    return coord_new
```

I update numba. The error:

```
NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function sortVertices failed at nopython mode lowering due to: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function make_quicksort_impl.<locals>.run_quicksort at 0x1298bc9d8>) found for signature:
 
run_quicksort(array(float64, 1d, C))
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'register_jitable.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.ov_wrap': File: numba/core/extending.py: Line 150.
    With argument(s): '(array(float64, 1d, C))':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_call_template'
  raised from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/types/functions.py:511\
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe try `argsort` with `kind='mergesort'`? Or `x = np.take(xc, indices)`?

Comment: Both won't work; mergesort generates a different kind of error:

'NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function sortVertices failed at nopython mode lowering due to: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'sort_func': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
File "../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/np/arrayobj.py", line 5032:
    def array_argsort_impl(arr):
        return sort_func(arr)
        ^

Comment: I'm not a `numba` expert, but just calling a sequence of `numpy` calls is not an optimal use of `numba`.  Even when it runs, the speedup will probably be modest, since those functions already use `numpy` compiled code.  And as you found here, you are more likely to find features that are not implements in `numba`, such as this sort.

Comment: Install the newest numba version first. hpaulj is right that a bunch of Numpy vectorized commands are hard/impossible to optimize for Numba. Write simple loops like in C if you have some C experience. With a newer version of Numba this example works, but slower than the original one. Sorting has always been slower in Numba and this is the dominating part here.

Comment: Thank you for your reactions. I am aware of the modest speedup. However, the function is nestled in other functions which do have much speedup (also @jit). Therefore i compiled this function also.